# Negative Definite Hessian implies Concave proof

Tags: hessian-matrix

I am struggling to find some proof about concavity and hessian matrix,
How can I proof:
If the Hessian Matrix of $f$ is Negative Definite, then $f$ is concave.
I will appreciate it if you can share with me the link to the proof thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have found it 
http://econ.ucsb.edu/~tedb/Courses/GraduateTheoryUCSB/BlumeSimonCh21.pdf
thanks for the help